# How do I preserve content in database while making on going changes to my code?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

How do I avoid overwriting my local database when doing a pull request from remote? further, if I use '.gitignore', will I be able to make structural changes to my DB in the future? (for example, if I want to make changes to a model)

I am currently using Django with the sqlite3 DB.

Comment: if you have the database in repository then that databasae will be usesd as your local database when pulling the repository, it happens like all other file when fetching from repo. And for the second question you can make structural changes in database when you have migrations in your repo, you pull migrations and ```migrate``` the changes.

Comment: This makes sense thanks

Comment: consider this as an answer if it helped